# Building Hadoop 1.2.1 core jar using ant - Failed

Tags: hadoop, ant, build

I need to make some modifications to the map class and reduce class from Hadoop, so, I have been trying to compile Hadoop 1.2.1 jar files using ant from the source files, but I always get the following error:

```
Buildfile: build.xml

clover.setup:

clover.info:
 [echo] 
 [echo]      Clover not found. Code coverage reports disabled.
 [echo]   

clover:

ivy-download:
  [get] Getting: http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.1.0   /ivy-2.1.0.jar
  [get] To: /home/user/Downloads/hadoop-1.2.1/ivy/ivy-2.1.0.jar
  [get] Not modified - so not downloaded

ivy-init-dirs:

ivy-probe-antlib:

ivy-init-antlib:

ivy-init:
[ivy:configure] :: Ivy 2.1.0 - 20090925235825 :: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ ::
[ivy:configure] :: loading settings :: file = /home/user/Downloads/hadoop-1.2.1/ivy/ivysettings.xml

ivy-resolve-common:

ivy-retrieve-common:
[ivy:cachepath] DEPRECATED: 'ivy.conf.file' is deprecated, use 'ivy.settings.file'  instead
[ivy:cachepath] :: loading settings :: file = /home/user/Downloads/hadoop-1.2.1/ivy/ivysettings.xml

init:
[touch] Creating /tmp/null1102494190
[delete] Deleting: /tmp/null1102494190
 [exec] svn: E155007: '/home/user/Downloads/hadoop-1.2.1' is not a working copy
 [exec] svn: E155007: '/home/user/Downloads/hadoop-1.2.1' is not a working copy

record-parser:

compile-rcc-compiler:

compile-core-classes:

compile-hdfs-classes:
[javac] Compiling 2 source files to /home/user/Downloads/hadoop-1.2.1/build/classes
[javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
[javac] 1 warning

compile-mapred-classes:
Trying to override old definition of task jsp-compile

create-native-configure:
 [exec] configure.ac:42: warning: AC_COMPILE_IFELSE was called before AC_USE_SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS
 [exec] ../../lib/autoconf/specific.m4:314: AC_GNU_SOURCE is expanded from...
 [exec] configure.ac:42: the top level
 [exec] configure.ac:42: warning: AC_COMPILE_IFELSE was called before AC_USE_SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS
 [exec] ../../lib/autoconf/specific.m4:314: AC_GNU_SOURCE is expanded from...
 [exec] configure.ac:42: the top level
 [exec] configure.ac:42: warning: AC_COMPILE_IFELSE was called before AC_USE_SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS
 [exec] ../../lib/autoconf/specific.m4:314: AC_GNU_SOURCE is expanded from...
 [exec] configure.ac:42: the top level
 [exec] configure.ac:48: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
 [exec]       If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
 [exec]       See the Autoconf documentation.
 [exec] autoreconf: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1

BUILD FAILED
/home/user/Downloads/hadoop-1.2.1/build.xml:634: exec returned: 1
```

Does anybody know what could be the problem? or knows how to create the jar files using ant?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was that it was missing a library.

Fixed just by installing libtool.

```
sudo apt-get install libtool
```

Now it will build successfully the project.

source: [link] http://desk.stinkpot.org:8080/tricks/index.php/2007/05/fixing-error-undefined-macro-ac_prog_libtool/